# How to upload Facebook status programmatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying  to upload Facebook status programmatically to my page, to make it simple, I tested it using  Facebook Graph API Explorer. Here is what I put in:

```
POST:  http://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/1027557373928902/feed
message: Nepal needs help. 
picture: http://dealsariel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/help_nepal.jpg
```

I did see the message (please see the screenshot), but, first, I hope it is displayed in status area (in red rectangle), not in the left side. Second, it did not show the picture? 
Thank you very much for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to post "as Page", you need to use a Page Token instead of a User Token. You need to authorize with the `publish_pages` and `manage_pages` permissions too, i assume you are using `publish_actions` with a User Token right now. After authorizing with the correct permissions, generate a Page Token by using the `/me/accounts` endpoint. User that Page token with the feed endpoint.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks Luschn, I might need spend some time to reaserch on it, will get back with update.

Comment: Hi luschn, thank you for the answer, it is the right answer, but I cannot vote now. I will do that as soon as I earned enough point. Thanks!

Comment: i believe you should be able to select it as answer without any additional points, and i think you get points for selecting it :)